# Foundation 4 Top-bar's toogle-topbar for medium up

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

Foundation 4's top-bar's toggle will activate for medium down screen size, how can I change toggle to activate for small instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this from Foundation docs:

```
$topbar-breakpoint: emCalc(940); /* Change to 9999px for always mobile layout */
$topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{$topbar-breakpoint})";
```

You need to change emCalc value.

Note that emCalc is SASS function that turns em's automatically into pixels. So by default its set to break at 940px.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't notice there's a topbar breakpoint option.